# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_date_time-vc80-mt-1_55.lib'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, boost-date-time

I have been trying to calculate number of days between two dates using Visual C++.
I am using visual studio 2005 and boost 1.55.0 for gregorian date_time library but got stuck in this error. #include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
Error   32  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_date_time-vc80-mt-1_55.lib'    LicenseMac
After doing some research in Project properties, I added boost library path in both C++ >> General >> Additional Include Directories and Linker >> .
I have two dates generated from System::DateTime.Now and stored in a text file for example
6/30/2016 0:0:0
5/8/2016 0:0:0

Would you please suggest me specific solution depending upon my system environment? Is there any other simple method in visual c++ for visual studio 2005 to calculate duration of days between above two days.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

Where can you find this file `boost_date_time-vc80-mt-1_55.lib` in your system? Try using the full path of this file. Later find out where this file exists **relatively** to the Boost library.

If this file doesn't exist, you probably didn't built it, or not downloaded it well.